# python: database formatted in txt e skip first line and first two columns

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have e database as normal txt named DB.TXT ( delimiter Tab is applied only the numbers),like this:

```
Date        Id  I   II  III IV  V
17-jan-13   aa  47  56  7   74  58
18-jan-13   ab  86  2   30  40  75
19-jan-13   ac  72  64  41  81  80
20-jan-13   ad  51  26  43  61  32
21-jan-13   ae  31  62  32  25  75
22-jan-13   af  60  83  18  35  5
23-jan-13   ag  29  8   47  12  69
```

I would like to know the code in Python for skip first line (Date, I, II, III, IV, V) and the first two columns ( Date and Id), while reading a text file. (With numbers residues should do sums and multiplications etc.)

After reading the txt file, it will appear like this:

47  56  7   74  58

86  2   30  40  75

72  64  41  81  80

51  26  43  61  32

31  62  32  25  75

60  83  18  35  5

29  8   47  12  69

The file is format txt, not CSV.

Comment: You have a tab-separated values file; a form of CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only going to do calculations on the rows, you can simply do:

```
with open("data.txt") as fh:
    fh.next()
    for line in fh:
        line = line.split()  # This split works equally well for tabs and other spaces
        do_something(line[2:])
```

If your needs are more complex, you're better off using a library like Pandas, which can take care of headers and label columns, as well as regex delimiters, and gives you easy access to columns:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("blah.txt", sep="\s+", index_col=[0,1])
data.values   # array of values as requested
data.sum()    # sum of each column
data.product(axis=1)    # product of each row
etc...
```

`sep` is a regex since you said it's not always `\t`, and `index_col` makes the first two columns column labels.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), to skip the first line, just advance the file iterator by calling `next(f)`. To skip the first two rows you could use `row = row[2:]`:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    next(f)   # skip the first line
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
        row = row[2:]        # skip the first two columns
        row = map(int, row)  # map the strings to ints
```

Comment: I have used this code:

import csv

def function(x,y,z,w,t):

    return (x-y)

filename=("DB.txt")

with open(filename,'r') as f:

     next(f)

     for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t'):

         row = row[2:]

         for line in f:

             numbers_str = line.split()

             numbers_int = [int(x) for x in numbers_str]

             print 

function(numbers_int[0],numbers_int[1],numbers_int[2],numbers_int[3]

,numbers_int[4]))

Error= invalid literal for int() with base 10: '17-Jan-13'

Comment: Print out `row`. You will see it is a list of items. It is essentially `numbers_str`. Don't use `for line in `f` -- the `csv.reader` is iterating through `f` for you already.

Comment: Thanks, very much: It works.

The code for those who need is  (Sorry for the formatting):

import csv

def function(x,y,z,w,t):
    return (x+y+z+w+t)

filename=('DB.TXT')
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
          next(f)
          for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t'):
             row = row[2:]
             numbers_int = [int(x) for x in row]
             print (function(numbers_int[0],numbers_int[1],numbers_int[2],numbers_int[3],numbers_int[4]))

Answer (score 0):

"the code in python" is pretty broad.  Using numpy, it's:

```
In [21]: np.genfromtxt('db.txt',dtype=None,skip_header=1,usecols=range(2,6))
Out[21]: 
array([[47, 56,  7, 74],
       [86,  2, 30, 40],
       [72, 64, 41, 81],
       [51, 26, 43, 61],
       [31, 62, 32, 25],
       [60, 83, 18, 35],
       [29,  8, 47, 12]])
```